# What is the most common way to say that my birthday is tomorrow?

Tags: future-time

I have encountered the following three structures, but I'm not sure how common are they for native speakers?

1. Tomorrow is my birthday.
2. Tomorrow will be my birthday.
3. It is my birthday tomorrow.

Comment: To my (British) ears, all three are fairly common.

Comment: 3a. It's my birthday tomorrow. Or 1a. Tomorrow's my birthday.

Comment: They are all common  It depends on the context.

Comment: Yes, all common in the States.

Comment: How about *my birthday is tomorrow*?

Answer (score -1):

3 is most common. 1 sounds rather formal. 2 is literary or poetic. (British English)